# what is wrong with my odbc_connect argument?

Tags: list, database-connection, swi-prolog, type-mismatch, mysql-odbc-connector

The odbc_connect seems to have a trouble in receiving the connection variable (the third variable)

Here is the code to connect to the database:

```
get_connect_info(_3400, _3454) :-
    _3400 = ['Alumni_admin', '123'],  % Assign a list instead of a var
    odbc:odbc_connect(alumni_universe, _3400, _3454).


query :-  
    get_connect_info(_3400, _3454),  
    odbc_query(_3454, 'SELECT * FROM silver_party_distance', List, [types([integer,default])]),  
    writeln(List),  
    fail.
```

However the response of the prolog is in error:

```
ERROR: Type error: list' expected, found _7968' (a var)
ERROR: In:
ERROR: [12] odbc:odbc_connect(alumni_universe,[user,pass],_8022)
```

What could be the remedy?